# Windows 7 64-bit compatible multi-function color laser printer recommendations

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, printer, compatibility

I'm looking for recommendations for Windows 7 64-bit compatible multi-function color laser printers.

The printer needs to scan, copy, fax, print in color.  Laser preferred.  USB or Network connectivity.

But most importantly it needs to work with Windows 7 64-bit.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with Samsung Laser printers in a 64-bit Vista & Server 2008 environment.  But looking at their support website, I didn't see Windows 7 listed.  But that might just be because the RTM isn't generally available until October.

I'd go for a Samsung, a Canon or an HP, personally.  Avoid Lexmark like the plague.

**Update**
My Samsung Laser now works great in a 64-bit Windows 7 environment.

Comment: +1 for Samsung, always worked for me. Personally, I've had issues with HP (mostly the crap that they want you to install along with the drivers).